# How to add transition in swipe detection in HTML into my apps?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad

I saw this site [padilicious](http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/) that help me alot in making my first app in iPad using HTML. My problem is, i'm trying to add some transition in swiping my page to another.

here is my code:

```
if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
    window.location.href = 'page1.html';
}
```

How can I add transform code using his code. I'm really new in this kind of field so I hope you can help me.
**EDIT:**
Here is the one that I should add to my code. [HTML Page Slide Without a Framework](http://css.dzone.com/articles/html-page-slide-without).  How should I combine this to codes?

Answer (score 0):

if you like you can use transform in css3, add on the document you want,like this:

```
-webkit-transform:translate(120px,0);
```

Comment: Then, where I should put that code. I mean, I know what code that I have to use but my question is, Where should I put that code.